# How to parse large complex data into individual elements using Java

Tags: java, file

I have file with over 100k records but not delimited. I need to get the data from the file individually. I want data individual as below and some times on set of tags don’t exist.

1. 98668792
2. Inac xml from start tag to end tag`enter code here`
3. Inac2 xml from start tag to end tag
4. Inac3 xml from start tag to end tag

Below is the sample data for one set, likewise I have 900k sets.

```
98668792TM12016-03-29     0372  —<Inac>
        0372  —9866879TM12015-03-29<tag1>data<tag1/>
    9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag2>data<tag2/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag3>data<tag3/>
    9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag4>data<tag4/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag5>data<tag5/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag6>data<tag6/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag7>data<tag7/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag8>data<tag8/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag9>data<tag9/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag10>data<tag10/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag11>data<tag11/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag12>data<tag12/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag13>data<tag13/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag14>data<tag14/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag15>data<tag15/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag16>data<tag16/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag17>data<tag17/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag18>data<tag18/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag19>data<tag19/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag20>data<tag20/><Inac/><Inac2>   9866879T12015-03-29 <tag1>data<tag1/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag2>data<tag2/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag3>data<tag3/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag4>data<tag4/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag5>data<tag5/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag6>data<tag6/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag7>data<tag7/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag8>data<tag8/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag9>data<tag9/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag10>data<tag10/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag11>data<tag11/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag12>data<tag12/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag13>data<tag13/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag14>data<tag14/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag15>data<tag15/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag16>data<tag16/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag17>data<tag17/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag18>data<tag18/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag19>data<tag19/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag20>data<tag20/><Inac2/><Inac3>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag3>data<tag3/>
   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag4>data<tag4/>   9866879TM12015-03-29 <tag5>data<tag5/><Inac3/>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: parsed the file line by line and searched for existence of start tag and if found parsing the lines until we get the end tag,in between these lines i am appending and took its complete xml.

Comment: please show the code you have so far